# How to create crystal reports using vb6 and mysql

Tags: mysql, vb6, crystal-reports

I want to create crystal reports using vb6 and mysql but providing the connection string in the code. I am able to successfully create the reports by using the report expert wherein i choose the database and tables fields manually. But my application is client-server based, where database will be on the server and the client will use this database to view the crystal report on his machine. I am using crystal reports 8.5.
Kindly help me find a solution for this.